# JS date converting

Tags: javascript, date

Hay, how can i turn a string like "04 Jan 2010" into a string like "1/4/2010". Can i do this with the JS date object?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/Parse) is what you're looking for?

If that doesn't do it, then [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) adds more robust parsing.

Comment: This correctly converts the string into a stamp, now i need to convert the stamp back into a string, in PHP i would use date("D M Y", $stamp);

Does js have something along those lines?

Comment: Thanks, this led to find the solution. Using a combination of getDate(), getYear(), and getDay().

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function `getYear()` is deprecated. You should use `getFullYear()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
[timeSolver.js](https://github.com/sean1093/timeSolver)

```
var dateString = timeSolver.getString("04 Jan 2010", "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

You can get date string by using this method:

> getString(date, format)

Hope this will help you!